# Importxml() returned "empty cells" or "formula parse error"

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I tried `Importhtml ("https://nepsealpha.com/investment-calandar/dividend","table",)` and then `Importxml("https://nepsealpha.com/investment-calandar/dividend",xpath)`. I found out xpath from "selectorgadget" extension of googlechrome, but still couldn't import it. It shows either "empty content" or formula parse error".

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve quite all the informations this way

```
=importxml(url,"//div/@data-page")
```

and then parse the json.

By script : `=getData("https://nepsealpha.com/investment-calandar/dividend")`

```
function getData(url) {
  var from='data-page="'
  var to='"></div></body>' 
  var jsonString = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().split(from)[1].split(to)[0].replace(/&quot;/g,'"')
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString).props.today_prices_summary.top_volume
  var headers = Object.keys(json[0]);
  return  ([headers, ...json.map(obj => headers.map(header => obj[header]))]);
}
```

### edit

to update periodically, add this script

```
function update(){
  var chk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange('A1')
  chk.setValue(!chk.getValue())
}
```

put a trigger as you wish on the update function and change as follows

```
=getData("https://nepsealpha.com/investment-calandar/dividend",$A$1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, can u please show me what shud i write in script to get data of that site to get data such as "dividend growth %", "bonus%" column data ?

Comment: what are the urls you use to retrieve that values?

Comment: I need a table from this site "https://nepsealpha.com/investment-calandar/dividend" into google sheets, which updates itself every day as the value changes in the table... (I have made a time trigger script) but cudnt scrap that table...

Comment: I have editing my answer.

Comment: It is not working yet, please check this file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1400zifxNv6goyMT0cOluHUzj4JbuRjxt5oZZgXyPcRY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: now it does, put the formula in A2

Comment: can you give me a feed-back?

Comment: actually i wanted to see "dividend growth%", "bonus" column from the website into sheets... its still now working..

Comment: these infirmations are not directly available by native google function since the page is built by javascript. Only symbol shareTraded closingPrice securityName securityId are available.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's not the answer you want to see.
It's impossible to get any content from this website using IMPORTXML or other tools included in Google Sheets.

It's generated using Javascript. Once Javascript is disabled no content is displayed:
[image]

It's done on purpose. Financial companies pay for live stock data and they don't want to share it with us for free.
So the site is protected against tools like importxml.

Comment: it seems that informations are stored in a big json.